# How to get a second execution using events in kernel?

Tags: c, kernel

basically someone told me that if i can execute 1 time in kernel i can obtain execution again so is that possible? if yes could anyone tell how how could i do that because i need to call a function after my DriverEntry has returned.

Comment: can you elaborate the question? can you be more specific on which kernel?

Comment: It sounds like whoever told you that may have had a very specific context in mind, or else may have simply been saying that whatever you do once, you can do again the same way (even though that's not universally true).  Who knows what features a random kernel for a random OS might have, but I would be surprised to discover one that had a generic replay facility.

Comment: @OznOg windows kernel drivers.

Comment: @John Bollinger me too and i guess it is possible but idk how to.